# Oracle connection problem on Mac OSX: "Status : Failure -Test failed: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection"

Tags: oracle, macos

I'm trying this with Oracle SQL Developer and am on an Intel MacBook Pro.  But I believe this same error happens with other clients.  I can ping the server hosting the database fine so it appears not to be an actual network problem.

Also, I believe I'm filling in the connection info correctly.  It's something like this:

```
host = foo1.com
port = 1530
server = DEDICATED
service_name = FOO
type = session
method = basic
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem turned out to be some kind of ACL problem.  I needed to SSH tunnel in through a "blessed host".  I put the following in my .ssh/config

```
Host=blessedhost
HostName=blessedhost.whatever.com
User=alice
Compression=yes
Protocol=2
LocalForward=2202 oraclemachine.whatever.com:1521

Host=foo
HostName=localhost
Port=2202
User=alice
Compression=yes
Protocol=2
```

(I don't think the second block is really necessary.)  Then I change the host and port in the oracle connection info to localhost:2202.

Answer (score 1):

That's the message you get when you don't have the right connection parameters. The SID, in particular, tends to trip up newcomers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect to database on other host then you need to know

- hostname
- port number (by default 1521)
- SID name

if you get the connection error that you mentioned in your question then you have not specified correctly either hostname or port number. Try

```
telnet hostname portnumber
```

from Terminal to verify if you can connect to portnumber (by default 1521) - if not then probably port number is incorrect.